# Unity C# Ingame datetime system has delay

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

My game implements a datetime system which contains 3 speeds:

Slow: 1 second = 10 in-game minutes,

Normal: 1 second = 2 in-game hours,

Fast: 1 second = 1 in-game day

Slow speed works fine, normal speed have a bit of delay, and fast speed is delay by a lot (like 2.5 sec for a day). Is it because the computer cannot handle too much operation? Is there any way to implement it? Thanks.

Below is my script, important part starts at the update function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

//Manage datetime
public class DateManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Singleton
    public static DateManager dateManager;

    //Get other objects
    private GameStatManager gameStatManager;

    //Local var
    private Text displayTime;
    private Text displayDate;
    private Image timeScaleImage;
    float counter;

    //Get speed icon
    public Sprite slow;
    public Sprite medium;
    public Sprite fast;

    //Output var
    public DateTime date;
    private float timeScale;

    void Start(){

        //Singleton
        dateManager = this;

        //Get other objects
        gameStatManager = GameObject.Find("GameStatManager").GetComponent<GameStatManager>();
        displayDate = transform.Find("Date").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        displayTime = transform.Find("Time").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        timeScaleImage = transform.Find("TimeScale").gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();

        //Set default
        timeScale = 1f;
        timeScaleImage.sprite = slow;
        counter = 0f;
        date = new DateTime(2010, 01, 01);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;

        if (counter >= 1f / timeScale){
            counter = 0f;
            date = date.AddMinutes(10);
            displayDate.text = date.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy");
            displayTime.text = date.ToString("HH:mmtt");  

            //To GSM
            gameStatManager.SetDate(date);
        }
    }

    //Button function
    public void ChangeTimeScale(){

        // 1f = 10mins/sec || 12f = 2hrs/sec || 144f = 1day/sec
        if (timeScale == 1f){
            timeScale = 12f;
            timeScaleImage.sprite = medium;
        }
        else if (timeScale == 12f){
            timeScale = 144f;
            timeScaleImage.sprite = fast;
        }
        else {
            timeScale = 1f;
            timeScaleImage.sprite = slow;
        }

        //To GSM
        gameStatManager.SetTimeScale(timeScale);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, you're resetting the counter to *0* any time it's greater than `1f/timeScale`. That means you "lose" however much it's over `1f/timeScale`. Maybe use `counter -= 1f/timeScale;` instead? Additionally, you're using `HH` and `tt` in the same date/time format string, which is odd - normally you'd use `h` (12-hour) when you're also including the am/pm designator.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I didn't think of the time lose. Now the normal speed works fine, but the fast speed still have some delay.  And thanks for reminding for the AM/PM part.

Comment: You would need to run your game at least 144fps for this to work. In your Update() method try a while instead an if since you need to add more then 10 minutes per Update() call.

Comment: @JeanLuc Oh, I see. Is it because only on 144fps or above I would be able to call the Update() for 144 times a second?

Comment: Yes. Unity will call Update() once per frame.